# Protobuf: how do I get right options order of a method?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am writing protoc plugin in Go which should generate documentation for our GRPC services and currently struggle in attempt to know right order of options.

First, how the protobuf looks like

```
 syntax = "proto3";
 option go_package = "sample";

 package sample

 import "common/extensions.proto"

 message SimpleMessage {
     // Id represents the message identifier.
     string id = 1;
     int64 num = 2;
 }

 message Response {
    int32 code = 1;
 }

 enum ErrorCodes {
     RESERVED = 0;
     OK    = 200
     ERROR = 6000
     PANIC = 6001
 }

 service EchoService {
     rpc Echo (SimpleMessage) returns (Response) {
        // common.grpc_status is an extension defined somewhere
        // these are list of possible return statuses
         option (common.grpc_status) = {
             status: "OK"
             status: "ERROR"
             status: "PANIC" // Every status string will must be one of ErrorCodes items
         };

         option (common.middlewares) = {
             middleware: "csrf"
             middleware: "session"
         }
     }
 };
```

As you see, there're two options here. The problem is `protoc` doesn't bind position directly to tokens. It leaves this information in a special sections where it can be restored via using so called "paths". And these paths are rely on order, while options are hidden and can only be retrieved using `proto.GetExtension` function which doesn't report option index either.
I need this token location information to report errors. Is there any way to get option index or something equivalent?

I am thinking about using standalone parser just to retrieve the right order, but this feels somewhat awkward. Hope there's a better way.

Comment: So, I moved the ugly way, with yet another parsing using great https://github.com/emicklei/proto (it would be even greater if it would provide token location)

Comment: BTW, https://github.com/emicklei/proto does provide token location now, so I can recommend this great library